# Upgrade blues - 14.4-16.4

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, upgrade

I ran do-release-upgrade from command line on my medical practices server. Things were going very smoothly and then the system hung up. I did a hard restart after waiting a long while. When the system camp back up each time would grash at Sbin/init stage which I understand to beginning command in the kernal  simply will not boot. During the boot sequence clearly there is something wrong here. I used rescue CD which booted the system right up. I ran "apt-get -f install" the install process picked up where it froze. It asked for a mysql password. I provided this but it would not accept it and just continued with the install process. After get to the end and running apt-get update the number of unmet dependencies were astronomical. After many hours, I tried aptitude and it seemed to handle the dependancy issues and reduced the number to about 12, but on boot up the system now gives a scary red screen with the ubuntu 16.04 header and several errors but it ends with ".dr m_kms_help:panic occurred, switching back to text console." Then it just freezes. When I use a different kernal in GRUB I get the can't locate sbin/init error. It states "target filesystem doesn't have a requested /sbin/init"

I figured if I could get just the remaining dependancies to to be met and run Apt-get upgrade/upgrade that it would work itself out in that process and perhaps reinstall missing dependancies. So once again I ran the rescue disc when I ran this all boots up well. I can see all my files are there but it appears I have DNS problems becuause when I run apt-get update/upgrade, I get one "update"- "unable to fetch some archives" and on "upgrade"- "unsolved host"  and on "apt-get -f install"- "failed to fetch" errors. I checked resolv.conf and it is none existent, nor will the application allow me to created it in Nano. I ping 8.8.8.8 and I get activity... "64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl =121 time =19.9ms......" etc. until I "control C" I am at wits end and unsure what to the next and all of my data is on this box and backed up. I am thinking I should start new but I need to know how to get my data off.

So I have three questions. 
1. Is there a way to get the box to connect for update and upgrades? After the aptitude correction something is grossly off with the DNS. Yet it pings just fine.
2. Can I just make a new drive and label this one sdb and pull my data folder over to the new machine?
Can't anyone help .. I am starting to feel a bit like Dorthy of Oz!
3. How can I get anew SBIN/init program in place so kernal can run it so I do not have to use the disc.

Comment: 0. This is why you make regular backups, including before a release-upgrade. They prevent little problems like these. 1. Probably. 2. Yes.,,but beware you don't overwrite your data and make your problem much, much harder. 3, Either complete the existing upgrade or clean-install anew. We cannot do much with multiple questions or edited summaries. It's likely that your system can be fixed...but doing so might not be a worthwhile use of your time. It's likely your data can be moved to a new install...but we know nothing about your data so cannot guess how much work that might be.